# undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7imwriteERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE

Tags: c++, python-3.x, linux, opencv

On Ubuntu 18.04, I have built a shared library using the following `compile.sh` pulled from other people's repo. I only modified the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Should I modified `OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR` and `OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR` because I was able to compile it and get `libRender.so`? I could NOT find these `OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR` and `OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR` on my desktop.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64

export OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR=/orions4-zfs/projects/jingweih/opencv/include
export OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR=/orions4-zfs/projects/jingweih/opencv/lib

export CFLAGS="-I/data/Taskonomy/opencv/include -I$OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR"
export DFLAGS="-L/data/Taskonomy/opencv/lib -L$OPENCV_LIBRARY_DIR -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui"

g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp $CFLAGS -O2 -o main.o -fPIC
g++ -std=c++11 main.o $CFLAGS $DFLAGS -O2 -o libRender.so -shared -fPIC

#g++ -std=c++11 main.o buffer.o loader.o render.o $CFLAGS $DFLAGS -o render -lcudart

#rm *.o
```

But after compiling, when I tried to use the library,

```
Render = cdll.LoadLibrary('./Render/libRender.so')
```

it raised the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualize_field.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Render.render as render
  File "/home/qimin/Projects/Cameralocalization/src/Render/render.py", line 4, in <module>
    Render = cdll.LoadLibrary('./Render/libRender.so')
  File "/home/qimin/anaconda3/envs/framenet/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/home/qimin/anaconda3/envs/framenet/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./Render/libRender.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7imwriteERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE
```

Here is the output of `ldd libRender.so`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce61af000)
libopencv_core.so.3.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4 (0x00007fb4da01d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb4d9c94000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb4d9a7c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb4d968b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb4d9487000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb4d9268000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb4d9060000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb4d8e43000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb4d8aa5000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb4db10d000)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be very appreciated.